# Missing Add Moles assembly

Tags: moles

I have been trying to install Moles but even though the installation goes through fine, I don't see Add Moles Assembly option when I right-clicked on a dll in References. What am I missing?

I installed x64 version (I'm on Windows 7) from here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22c07bda-ffc9-479a-9766-bfd6ccacabd4/

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I don't have admin rights on my machine. Could that be a problem?

After installation, I went to About Microsoft Visual Studio and do not see any mentions of Pex or Moles on installed products.

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Same here...I installed Moles(x86) and been trying every othe roption but don't see it... Did you have any luck with it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen.  I believe we fixed the issue by using the administrative login.  It was at least one year ago, so I could be wrong.